# Google QUERY to SELECT X column where MAX=(Y column)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to pull the `object_ID` from column `A` that matches the `MAX` value of column `N`, all of which is pulling from another worksheet within the same document.

Can't quite seem to make it work right though and always end up with various error messages. I think the `where MAX(N)` segment is causing the issue.

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(QUERY('Compiled Table'!$A$1:$N$104,"select (A) where MAX(N) group by A", 1), "select * offset 1", 0), "0")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try this part as such:

```
=QUERY('Compiled Table'!A1:N104,"select A, MAX(N) group by A")
```

Comment: Thanks! That pulls both the object_ID from A and the max value of N, but I was able to adjust my table since it was a more efficient way of getting both numbers anyway. You're a lifesaver!